# RTCClient : You have to be logged in in order to use Chat API

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, quickblox

Calling below code to start video call using QuickBlox, But getting 'You have to be logged in in order to use Chat API' error even after calling login API.

```
        //Authorise user/Create session
    QBRequest.logIn(withUserLogin: userDef.value(forKey: "userID") as! String, password: ConstantObjectFile.quickBloxPassWord, successBlock: { [self] (response, user) in
        print(response)
        print(user)

        //Initiate call
        let idd = "125914156"//self.contactListArray[sender.tag].following_user_id
        let myNumber = Int(idd)!
        let opponentsIDs = [myNumber]
        let newSession = QBRTCClient.instance().createNewSession(withOpponents: opponentsIDs as [NSNumber], with: .video)
        // userInfo - the custom user information dictionary for the call. May be nil.



        let userInfo = ["key":"value"] // optional
        newSession.startCall(userInfo)

    }, errorBlock: { (response) in
        print(response)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be connected to chat before creating a call session. Here is the guide - https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/ios-chat-connection#connect-to-chat-server

QuickBlox WebRTC signaling goes over XMPP protocol (that's why you have to be connected to chat first)